# Left Join SQL based on criteria that may be missing

Tags: sql, join

I've got several tables that I want to merge for one big query. The criteria for the search are based on two tables: `section_types` and `sections`. I want to pull all `section_types` and their associated `sections` where the `sections` match certain criteria, PLUS any `section_types` that are active but don't have any `sections` associated. It seems like a basic `LEFT JOIN`, but I think because some of my filter criteria are based on `sections`, I can't get `section_types` that have no associated `sections`

```
`section_types`

id | name | active
---+------+-------
 1 | a    | 1
 2 | b    | 0
 3 | c    | 1

`sections`

type | issue | location 
-----+-------+----------
1    | 0611  | 1
2    | 0611  | 1
1    | 0511  | 1
```

Say I want to pull all sections for issue 0611 at location 1, plus any empty section types. Like so:

(edited. see below)

But I'm only getting `section_types` that have corresponding `sections`. So in this query, `section_types` row 3 would not show up. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:

I'm getting all the `section_types` now, but not all the `sections` I need. I guess `LEFT JOIN` will do that. There can be many `sections` for each `section_type`, or none. My query is at this point now:

```
SELECT * FROM `section_types` st
    RIGHT JOIN `sections` s
        ON s.type=st.id
            AND s.issue='0611'
            AND s.location=1
WHERE st.active OR s.issue IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY st.id
```

which gets me:

```
id | name | active | issue | location
---+------+--------+-------+---------
1  | a    | 1      | 0611  | 1
2  | b    | 0      | 0611  | 1
3  | c    | 1      |       |
```

but I still need that second type-1 `section`

Comment: Actually, in my tests all three section_types rows return. Row 2 is not active but has a section row and row 3 is active and therefore the other part of the OR is ignored.

Comment: What is the logic you want? You want all section_types that are active or...what? Is it that you want to filter out any non-active section_types that have no section rows of any kind regardless of issue or location?

Comment: The second type = 1 issue is filtered out because its issue does not match the filter of `0611`.

Comment: your query (the LEFT JOIN version) seems 100% correct to what you describe .

Comment: If you need to navigate from session to session_type to other sessions, you need to join one more time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you need?

All section_types and ALL their related sections where at least one section has issue `'0611'` and location `1`. Plus all the rest section_types that are active:

```
    SELECT *
    FROM section_types st
        JOIN sections s
            ON s.type = st.id
    WHERE EXISTS
        ( SELECT *
            FROM sections s2
            WHERE s2.type = st.id
              AND s2.issue = '0611'
              AND s2.location = 1
        ) 
UNION ALL
    SELECT *, NULL, NULL, NULL
    FROM section_types st
    WHERE st.active
      AND NOT EXISTS
        ( SELECT *
            FROM sections s2
            WHERE s2.type = st.id
              AND s2.issue = '0611'
              AND s2.location = 1
        ) 
ORDER BY id
```

Comment: Although I got rid of the first EXISTS - it seemed to be causing trouble. I just used `ON s.type=st.id AND s.issue='0611' AND s.location=1` and that seemed to work great. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**

I deleted this, but based on the conversation, I think it accomplishes what you're looking for.

**ORIGINAL**

Feels like a hack... but I think it works.

```
Declare @tmp TABLE(
    id int,
    name varchar(50),
    active int,
    type int,
    issue int,
    location int
)
Insert Into @tmp
SELECT * FROM section_types st
    LEFT JOIN sections s
        ON st.id=s.type
            AND s.issue='0611'
            AND s.location=1 
WHERE st.active = 1 OR s.issue IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY st.id

Select * FROM @tmp 
UNION 
Select 
    *, NULL, NULL, NULL 
From 
    section_types 
WHERE 
    id NOT IN ( SELECT id FROM @tmp)
    AND active = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You just have your tables reversed. `LEFT OUTER JOIN` requires the *left* table to have a row for the `ON` condition. Use a `RIGHT OUTER JOIN` or swap the tables.

Comment: You know, I realized that right as you were posting this. The problem now, though, is that I'm only getting one result per `section_type`. Which `LEFT JOIN` would do. I've got all the `section_types` but I don't have all the `sections` I need. Thoughts?